# Kotlin: Statement to Lambda

Tags: lambda, kotlin

How can I make a Kotlin statement to lambda?

I know that you can do that:

```
fun foo() : () -> Unit {
    return { println("Hello World") }
}

//more beautiful:
fun foo() : () -> Unit = { println("Hello World") }
```

Is it also possible to create an anonymous lambda without the curly brackets `{...}`?

In particular in a switch statement, the usual way with curly brackets doesn't look good.

```
fun bar(i: Int) : () -> Unit {

    return when (i) {

        0 -> { { println("Hello") } }

        1 -> { { println("World") } }

        else -> { { println("Bye") } }
    }
}
```

Looking forward to your response!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly braces are the [syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#lambda-expression-syntax) for a lambda expression, you can't create one without them.

In a `when` statement, you can either give your branch a block body, and return the lambda as its last expression, or you can have a single expression branch return a lambda by wrapping it in parentheses (otherwise it would be interpreted as a branch that executes the code inside the braces):

```
when (x) {
    "block body returning an Int" -> {
        // do stuff
        25
    }
    "block body returning a lambda" -> {
        // do stuff
        { println("Hello") }
    }
    "single expression returning an Int" -> 25
    "single expression returning a lambda" -> ({ println("Hello") })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like neither `{{` nor `({` from zsmb13's answer, you can make it look slightly nicer by defining a rather trivial function:

```
fun <A> lambda(x: A) = x

// usage
return when (i) {
    0 -> lambda { println("Hello") }
    1 -> lambda { println("World") }
    else -> lambda { println("Bye") }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without curly braces and looking better.

```
fun getDayType(day: String): String {
return  when (day) {
        "SATURDAY" -> "Half Day"
        "SUNDAY" -> "Holyday"
        else -> "running day"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `when` is used as an expression, a value must be returned, [If it is used as an expression, the value of the satisfied branch becomes the value of the overall expression (Just like with if, each branch can be a block, and its value is the value of the last expression in the block.)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), if you look at the grammar of the [when-expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#when-expression), it can be seen that is made up by when-entries whose right part is in turn formed by [controlStructerBodies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#control-structures) and these are compounded by blocks, so when you use only a pair of curly braces `{}` Kotlin recognizes it as a [block](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#block) whose return value is the last expression inside the block, so for this one to be a lambda, a second pair of curly braces is required.

Returns a lambda because is the last and only expression inside the block:

```
    fun returnLambda(choice: Boolean): ()-> String {
        return when (choice) {
            true ->  {{"Hello"}}
            false -> {{"World"}}
        }

    }
```

Returns a String because is the last and only expression inside the block:

```
fun returnString(choice: Boolean): String{
    return when(choice){
        true -> {"Hello"}
        false -> {"world"}
    }
}
```

This way you can execute different expressions and return a value within the same block:

```
fun returnString(choice: Boolean): String {
    return when (choice) {
        true -> {
            println("Hello")
            println("world")
            "Hello"
        }
        false -> {
            "world"
        }
    }
}
```